# Chrome extension: Click event in tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hej,

I'm searching the Chrome API the whole day but can't find the answer. Quick: is it possible to add a icon to a tab and append a click listener? Or a click listener on the tab in general?

Thanks!

Comment: "icon to a tab" like a favicon, or a page action?

Comment: "click listener on the tab" on the tab ui itself, or the tab's page?

Comment: on a tab itself. I want a specified action performed when clicking on a tab. E.g. I'm in tab StackOverflow and have a second tab with youtube. I want to click on the YT tab without leaving SO and perform a action in the YT tab.

Comment: yes like a favicon. possible is also a dropdown on the tab ui. just something to interact with the clicked tab without leaving the current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible with [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) api. Or with [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

## injectedScript.js

```
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click',function () {
    alert('button click!');
});
```

## manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/webPage.html"],
      "js": ["injectedScript.js"]
    }
],
```

## webPage.html

`<button id="btn1">clickMe!</button>`

For more information see [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)

### Edit:

You can't add event to the tab itself, i think that the best way is to do this, is context menu. This example it's ugly code but this make the work...
(And i'm sorry about my english).

## manifest.json

```
 "background":{"scripts":["background.js"]},
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs","activeTab","<all_urls>"]
```

## background.json

```
function apdateTabList() {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({url:'*://*/*'}, function (tabs) {
            var currTab;
            for (var i=0; currTab = tabs[i];i++) {
                chrome.contextMenus.create({
                    id : currTab.id.toString(),
                    title: currTab.title || currTab.url,
                    contexts:['all'],
                    onclick : function(info) {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(Number(info.menuItemId), {code:'alert("injected")'});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
apdateTabList();
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onMoved.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onDetached.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onAttached.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(apdateTabList);
chrome.tabs.onReplaced.addListener(apdateTabList);
```

Comment: nice start. But I didn't want to click on a button but on the tab itself to perform an action. And this tab must not be the actiive on.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no UI you can create on the tab *itself*.

Clicking on the tab is not something you can catch - the only event you can get is [changing of the active tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated), and you can't really say how that happened, and you can't prevent it - it already happened by the time you receive the event.